# Why it prints me null in 'c '

Tags: c

I get a file with a periodic table and I put it in the function `readfile` and then I read the file. But when I print the `table1` it prints `(null)0`. Why?

```
#define SIZE 200

void readfile(FILE *fp1, char ***table1, int ***graph) {    
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    char table[SIZE];
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("The file is incorrect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((fgets(table, SIZE, fp1)) != NULL) {
        counter++;
    }
    (*table1) = (char **)malloc(counter);
    (*graph) = (int**)malloc(counter);
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        (*table1) = (char *)malloc(counter);
        (*graph) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * counter);
    }
    int j = 0;
    while ((fgets(table, SIZE, fp1)) != NULL) {
        sscanf(table,"%s %d\n", (*table1)[j], &i);
        j++;
    }
    printf("%s%d\n", (*table1)[j]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argb[]) {
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen(argb[1], "r");
    char **table1 = NULL;
    int **graph = NULL;
    readfile(fp1, &table1, &graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have way too many `*`.

Comment: Being a three-star programmer is not a compliment in C.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer or http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouMightBeaThreeStarProgrammer and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammerExamples

Comment: Note that you have not supplied any input data.  Apart from 'i print the table1 it prints (null)0', you have not provided any details of your own debugging :(

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- You pass a triple pointer for `graph` which is probably incorrect.
- You do not allocate the correct amount of memory for the arrays, nor for the strings.
- You do not `rewind()` the file after the first reading loop.
- You do not check for memory allocation failure.
- You do not check for file format mismatch.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 200

void *xalloc(size_t size) {
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

int readfile(FILE *fp1, char ***tablep, int **graphp) {
    int i, counter = 0;
    char buf[SIZE];
    char **table;
    int *graph;

    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("The file is incorrect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // count how many lines
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp1) != NULL) {
        counter++;
    }
    table = xalloc(sizeof(*table) * counter);
    graph = xalloc(sizeof(*graph) * counter);
    rewind(fp1);
    for (i = 0; i < counter && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp1) != NULL; i++) {
        table[i] = xalloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
        if (sscanf(table, "%s %d", table[i], &graph[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "file format error at line %d\n", i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    *tablep = table;
    *graphp = graph;
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp1;
    char **table = NULL;
    int *graph = NULL;
    int count = 0;

    if (argc > 2) {
        fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        count = readfile(fp1, &table, &graph);
        printf("read %d records\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```